# How to sort files using the File command based on encodings

Tags: bash, sorting, encoding, utf-8

How can I sort these files into different files based on encodings?

When I do `file *` I get a result such as following with different files with so many different encodings. How do I sort every single file in a folder into different folders based on encodings?

```
AmericanDreamsS01E17_en.srt:                        Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
The_Last_Mimzy_en.srt:                              Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
Everybody_Hates_Chris_S04_E06_en.srt:               ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
Blackish_S01_E24_en.srt:                            OS/2 REXX batch file, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
Coyote_Ugly_en.srt:                                 Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
Coyote_Ugly_en.txt:                                 UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
Crash_en.srt:                                       UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators.
Weeds_S02E12_en.srt:                                C++ source, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
Weeds_S02E12_en.txt:                                UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
WeWereSoldiers_en.srt:                              ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
WeWereSoldiers_en.txt:                              UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
Without_A_Paddle_en.srt:                            UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From the `man file` documentation, you will need to modify the file command to use the `--no-pad` option for this solution to format the output white space correctly.

The file command is piped to awk so we can specify the field separator and then reverse the fields and simply pipe to sort. See [Schwartzian_transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

`file --no-pad * | awk -F ':' '{print $2": "$1}' | sort`

This uses all built-ins and does not require any external programs.

If you prefer to keep the encodings in their right column, the `-k` option can be used in the other solution provided by @Bayou.

Per the comment also by Bayou, you can sort this inside awk without the additional pipe, but this also does not allow you to use things like `uniq`.

`file --no-pad * | awk -F ':' '{print $2": "$1|"sort"}'`

Such as, this, but again, you can leverage awk in more robust ways:

`file --no-pad * | awk -F ':' '{print $2": "$1}' | sort | uniq`

Comment: Two pipes would be too much overload. Try to do it in `awk` alone (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort` command for this:

> ```
>   -k, --key=KEYDEF
>           sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
> ```

Therefore the command would be:

```sh
$ find . | sort -k 2
WeWereSoldiers_en.srt:                              ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
Weeds_S02E12_en.srt:                                C++ source, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
Everybody_Hates_Chris_S04_E06_en.srt:               ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
AmericanDreamsS01E17_en.srt:                        Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
Coyote_Ugly_en.srt:                                 Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
The_Last_Mimzy_en.srt:                              Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
Blackish_S01_E24_en.srt:                            OS/2 REXX batch file, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
Weeds_S02E12_en.txt:                                UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
Coyote_Ugly_en.txt:                                 UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
WeWereSoldiers_en.txt:                              UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
Crash_en.srt:                                       UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators.
Without_A_Paddle_en.srt:                            UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to move the files to a new directory depending on the file type, then this script will help you :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'find'
require 'fileutils'

search_in='.'
files = []

Dir.mkdir search_in + '/arranged' unless File.exists? search_in + '/arranged'

arrange = {
     'ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators' => 'ASCIIWITHCRLF',
     'C++ source, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators' => 'CPPUTF8',
     'ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators' => 'ISO8859CRLF',
     'Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators' => 'LEUTF16',
     'Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators' => 'NONISOEXASCIICRLF',
     'OS/2 REXX batch file, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators' => 'OS2REXXBATCHUTF8CRLF',
     'UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators' => 'UNICODEBOMUTF8CRLF',
     'UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines' => 'UNICODEUTF8LONGLINES',
     'UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators' => 'UNICODEUTF8LONGLINESNOLT',
}


arrange.each do |key,value|
    FileUtils.mkdir_p search_in + '/arranged/' + value unless File.exists? search_in + '/arranged/' + value
end

Find.find(search_in) do |path|
  file_type = system('file -b ' + path)
  FileUtils.cp(path, search_in + '/arranged/' + arrange[file_type]) if arrange.key?(file_type)
end
```

Its Ruby. Good luck!